# How to work around setting innerHTML causing escape sequences to expand?

Tags: javascript, html, escaping

I am trying to avoid a cross-site scripting vulnerability on my server. Before any user-inputted string is embedded within HTML or sent to client-side javascript code it is escaped ('<' replaced with '&lt;', '&' replaced with '&amp;', etc.) When embedding into HTML this works mostly fine; the HTML code produced does not contain any HTML elements inside the user-provided string. However, when the client-side javascript inserts HTML into the document, the escape sequences get expanded back into their special characters, which can result in user-inputted  tags appearing in the document HTML. Here's approximately what I'm doing, javascript client-side:

```
// response_data received from XMLHttpRequest and parsed as JSON
var s = "";
for (var i = 0; i < response_data.length; ++i) {
    s += "<p>";
    s += response_data[i];
    s += "</p>";
}
console.log(s);
elem.innerHTML = s;
```

Suppose the user inputted the string `"abcde <script>alert("Hello!");</script>"` earlier. Then response_data could be `["abcde &lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;Hello!&quot;);&lt;/script&gt;"]`. The print to console shows s to be `"<p>abcde &lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;Hello!&quot;);&lt;/script&gt;</p>"`. However, when I assign elem.innerHTML, I can see in Inspect Element that the inner HTML of the element is actually `<p>abcde <script>alert("Hello!");</script></p>`! I don't think it executed, probably because of some browser security features regarding script tags within p tags, but it's obviously not very good. How do I work around this?

Code snippet (run and inspect element over the text created, it shows a script tag within the p tag):

```js
var div_elem = document.querySelector("div");
div_elem.innerHTML = "<p>&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;Hello!&quot;);&lt;/script&gt;</p>";
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`.  Text nodes are not interpreted as html or as script.

Comment: you don't need to worry about script tags like that, it's onerror, onmouseover, etc that you need to watch out for.

Comment: Can you reproduce it with a runnable snippet? (`<>` toolbar button). If you do what you say you shouldn't get HTML tags from `&lt;` ([demo](https://codepen.io/kAlvaro/pen/LYGKZLj)).

Comment: @Álvaro González added a code snippet

Comment: Thank you. Your snippet seems to work correctly. What's the exact issue? You see the script tag **rendered** as text, as expected.

Comment: @Álvaro González Well, that there is a script tag within the p tag, you can see in Inspect Element. In this specific case it didn't execute the injected code but I'm wondering if it will be a problem if later on I'm inserting something into a tag other than a p tag...

Comment: Not in my browsers (Firefox and Chrome on Win64). Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Use `innerText`, it's like `innerHTML` but it's treated as pure text and won't decode the HTML entities.
**Edit:**

Set innerHTML to the p tags, then set the actual text using innerText on the tag

```
elem.innerHTML = "<p></p>";
elem.childNodes[0].innerText = s;
```

Comment: that won't show entities correctly though, right? they will appear escaped as code...

Comment: `&lt;` will be rendered as `<` as text, but won't be treated as HTML

Comment: This will cause the "<p>" and "</p>" to appear as text rather than as HTML tags. I only want to escape the text inside the paragraph tags. (I've tried this, BTW.)

Comment: So then `var p = document.createElement('p'); p.innerText = 'whatever'; elem.appendChild(p)`

Comment: you could dynamically create a new p tag, then set the contents to the escaped  text, then append the tag instead of using innerHTML

Comment: did they spec `innerText` on Node or is textContent still the official property? There are slight differences...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText